# Translation of "to catch up" (sharing recent happenings with someone you haven't seen lately)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, verbos

In English, "to catch up (with each other)" can be used to describe two people that haven't seen each other in a while that are sharing recent events in their lives with each other. For example:

- "I haven't seen you in forever. We should get together and catch up sometime!"
- "It was great to finally be able to catch up."

How can this sense be translated to Spanish?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use "ponerse al día":

> No nos hemos visto en mucho tiempo. Deberíamos quedar un día para *ponernos al día*.

Comment: Or "ponernos al tanto", sound less redundant in your example.